# Mail rules not working automatically, only manually

Tags: mail.app, email

I'm not sure if I don't understand the concept of Mail rules correctly, but I think this isn't the problem here.

I believe it has something to do with the general setup.

I want to have a rule that moves all emails that I receive with a `.rar` attachment into spam.

This is my rule:
[image: Rule setup]

*Translated (because the screenshot is german):*

- apply when all conditions are met
- Name of the attachment ends with .rar
- Account (my account where I want this rule to work)
- Move Email into spam folder

For some reason this isn't working when I test it. The email stays where it is.
When I open the rule change something and change it back (to save it and trigger this message) I will get this popup:
[image: Popup]

*Translated (because the screenshot is german):*
Are you sure you want to apply your rule to the selected mailboxes? The rule could change the contents of the mailbox. Active rules only apply to new messages. (my english isn't the best, but I hope you can understand the popup)

When I click on `Apply` the email that is still (already) in the inbox gets moved in the spam folder like it should. Just not automatically when receiving messages.

Could one of the following be the problem or is my setup wrong?

- it is a shared mailbox that my coworkers also use (with other clients, Outlook on Mac/ Windows)
- it's an Exchange 2013 (managed through our hoster, not possible to set this rule there) mailbox
- on the server are some other rules for messages but they won't apply in this example (to point it out again, I can't set up the attachment type on the server. Only IF the message contains ANY attachment)

Forgot to mention: Yes the checkbox on `Active` is checked.

Comment: Just guessing, but have you tried removing the dot in `.rar`, that is, changing the rule to "Any attachment type ends with rar"?

Comment: @jaume I can try that. But as I said, when triggering the popup it will execute the rule and the email gets moved correctly. The only thing not working is that is happens automatically when such emails enters my inbox.